# Can I call functions inside PORT MAPs?

Tags: vhdl

Can I call functions like:

`label1: component_name PORT MAP (x AND y, b SSL 3, output);`

In VHDL?

I searched a lot until I decided to post here, and also read the VHDL manual, but it doesn't say you can't. Although it doesn't show it's possible either.

I'm on macOS right now, so I can't test it.

EDIT: I'm using Altera Quartus 16.0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.6.3 Port clauses para 6. In -2008 you can use an expression as an actual which will produce an anonymous concurrent  signal assigned the expression in same block the external block (component) is elaborated into, causing a delta cycle delay. It's the equivalent of adding an intermediary signal.

Comment: @user1155120 makes a good point - which vhdl edition are you referring too?

Comment: Port map expressions are supported in later versions of Xilinx's Vivado with 2008 mode enabled. See UG901, Supported -2008 features, Miscellaneous, Expressions in Port Maps.

Answer (score 2):

It will depend a lot on the compiler unfortunately.

As a relevent aside, expressions such as

```
x and y
```

are treated differently from function calls

```
and_fn(x,y)
```

I have successfully used code with fully qualified associations, and function calls rather than expressions, such as:

```
label1: component_name 
port map(
   a => and_fn(x,y),
   b => myfunc(),
   c => output
);
```

The definitive document is the Language Reference Manual, but the point is moot - try it in your toolset, support and compliance varies.

Comment: As OllieB notes support for this -2008 feature varies by vendor. It can require a lot of work to implement and without synthesis vendor support wouldn't be generally useful. A chicken or the egg conundrum. And OllieB's `myfunc()` is not a valid VHDL expression, there's no place empty parentheses are allowed.

Comment: What compiler did you use? I'm using Altera Quartus 16.0, but I'll only be able to test it in the compiler later. Your answer was already really helpful :)

Comment: I use modelsim + quartus 12 -> 16, and ise + vivado, various editions. I can't rememeber which one worked.